# При наведении курсора фон кнопки и текст должны изменяться снизу вверх

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Мне необходимо создать кнопку, при наведении на которую, нужно не только заливать цвет фона снизу вверх, но и менять цвет текста снизу вверх.

У меня получилось [с этим решением в  CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562340/css-background-fills-on-hover-from-bottom-to-top), что фон заполняется при наведении снизу вверх, но надо также чтобы изменялся внутренний цвет текста снизу вверх:

```
<style>
a {
           background-image: linear-gradient(to top, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
           background-size: 100% 200%;
           background-position: top;
           transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out; /** I've changed the time for demo purposes **/
           color: black;
       }

       a:hover {
           background-position: bottom;
       }
</style>
<a href="#">I'm a link</a>
<a href="#">I'm another link</a>
```

Вот [скриншот](https://ibb.co/kKV5gPh) того, что именно мне нужно.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56632856/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На CSS и без использование градиента

```css
button.button {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button::before, .button::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 100%;
}

.button::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.button:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.button:hover::after {
  color: #ddd;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" data-text="Div">Div</div>
<a href="#" class="button" data-text="Links">Links</a>
<button class="button" data-text="Button">Button</button>
```

UPD:
Теперь кнопка может быть просто элементов типа (span, div и т.п.), ссылкой (a) или кнопкой (button)

Comment: добавьте контуры кнопки и конечно нужно сделать изменение цвета текста, как в вопросе (+) и ешё,- кнопка должна работать, как ссылка. см. предыдущий ответ

Answer (score 6):

Используйте применение дополнительного слоя для фона и раскрасьте текст, используя также фон. Затем просто одновременно анимируйте их:

```css
a {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red 50%, #000 50%);
  
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
a:before {
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
}

a,
a:before {   
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:hover:before{
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Ссылка</a>
<a href="#">Другая ссылка</a>
```

Вы также можете сделать это в виде нескольких фонов без использования дополнительного элемента (не работает на Fiferox)

```css
a {
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;

  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to top, red 50%, #000 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
  
  -webkit-background-clip: text,padding-box;
  background-clip: text,padding-box;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;  
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover{
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Ссылка</a>
<a href="#">Другая ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Последний пример работает в мозилле, но красный цвет перекрывает текст)